# Does autoboxing perform better than custom wrapper types?

Tags: scala, generics, autoboxing

If I have a generic parameter that I am resolving via pattern matching to a primitive such as `Int`, is auto-boxing cheaper than using a custom wrapper type? E.g.

```
def test[A](x: A): Int = x match {
  case i: Int => i
  case _ => -1
}
```

versus

```
case class NumChannels(value: Int)

def test[A](x: A): Int = x match {
  case n: NumChannels => n.value
  case _ => -1
}
```

Does the first approach offer any performance benefits? Is this situation the same if the method was using `Any` instead:

```
def test(x: Any): Int = ...
```

?

Comment: What were your profiling results and how were they surprising?

Comment: I was not profiling. I'm trying to make a decision which kind of API to settle on.

Comment: Why do you not profile and make your decision based on the results, rather than relying on speculations?

Comment: No speculations—I want to know technically what the difference between the two versions is (if there is any). That's a question for people familiar with how autoboxing works in Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are look at the output of `javap` (only the parts which differ):

- The version using `Int`:

> ```
>  10: invokestatic  #17                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt:(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
>  13: istore_3      
>  14: iload_3
> ```

- The version using `NumChannels`:

> ```
>   10: checkcast     #12                 // class app/benchmark/scala/benchmark3b/NumChannels
>   13: astore_3      
>   14: aload_3       
>   15: invokevirtual #16                 // Method app/benchmark/scala/benchmark3b/NumChannels.value:()I
> ```

One could assume that the first version should be faster. The 3rd version using `Any` results in the same as the first version.

Yet a micro benchmark using JMH shows no real difference:

```
Benchmark                             Mode   Samples         Mean   Mean error    Units 
a.b.s.benchmark3a.Benchmark3a.run    thrpt         5       42,352        0,480   ops/ms 
a.b.s.benchmark3b.Benchmark3b.run    thrpt         5       42,793        1,439   ops/ms
```

Using Oracle JDK 1.8, Scala 2.10.3, Linux 32-Bit.

---

1st benchmark:

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
object BenchmarkState {
  final val n = 10000

  val input = 
    Array.range(0, n).map {
      n =>
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
          n
        } else {
          "" + n
        }
    }
}

class Benchmark3a {
  def test[A](x: A): Int = x match {
    case i: Int => i
    case _ => -1
  }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  def run() = {
    var sum = 0
    var i = 0
    while (i < BenchmarkState.n) {
      sum += test(BenchmarkState.input(i))
      i +=1
    }
    sum
  }
}
```

---

2nd benchmark

```
case class NumChannels(value: Int)

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
object BenchmarkState {
  final val n = 10000

  val input = 
    Array.range(0, n).map {
      n =>
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
          NumChannels(n)
        } else {
          "" + n
      }
    }
}

class Benchmark3b {
  def test[A](x: A): Int = x match {
    case n: NumChannels => n.value
    case _ => -1
  }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  def run() = {
    var sum = 0
    var i = 0
    while (i < BenchmarkState.n) {
      sum += test(BenchmarkState.input(i))
      i +=1
    }
    sum
  }
}
```

---

In previous versions I used `Seq` and methods `map` and `sum`, and both versions perform equally as well, but they only achieve around 4 ops/ms.

Even using `Array` and `while` does not reveal a real difference.

So I would say that this (isolated) API design decision won't affect performance.

---

Resources

- [How can I use JMH for Scala benchmarks together with sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23760056/2390083)
  (I have used the setup described in the selected answer)

Comment: Thanks for the extensive test; which benchmark framework have you used here?

Comment: JMH - fairly well hidden in the middle of the answer :-). I have added a link. As far as I know the sbt-jmh plugin currently only covers Scala based benchmarks (as for Scala/Java comparisons I use the maven-based approach)